# Set Object key as variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, object, key

I have looked at some other questions and they don't seem to address the particular issue I am encountering.  Basically, I want to set the key of an object with a variable and then change that variable.  I am using this to dynamically increment the keys in the object.

```
var x = 0;
var object = {};
object[x] = 1;
x+1;
object[x] = 2;
```

The above will produce undefined for `object[1]` and `object[2]` and 2 for `object[x]`.  I would like the output to be 1 for `object[1]` and 2 for `object[2]`.  Is this possible?

Comment: Then why do you start with `x = 0;`? And you're not incrementing `x` either btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've written `object[0] = 1; object[0] = 2`. If you want the keys to match the values, use matching keys and values.

Hint: Start with `x = 1` instead of `x = 0`.

Next, you've written `x+1;`, which is a do-nothing statement. If you want to add one to `x` and assign the result to `x`, you need to *assign the result back to x`. Any of these will do:

```
x = x + 1
x += 1
x++
```

Comment: OP effectively wrote `object[0] = 2;` :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var x = 1;
var object = {};
object[x] = 1;
x=x+1;
object[x] = 2;
```

You don't give the new value to x when adding 1 and also initialize x with 1 not 0 to get your result.